# What is the default scope of a Named CDI bean?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, jboss-weld, named

Is there any default scope for a `@Named` CDI bean without additional `@...Scoped` annotations? I have not found any relevant information in the [official Weld documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/).

A `@Named` bean can be accessed over JSF without additional annotations, so some implicit scope seems likely.

Thank you

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The default scope is the dependent pseudo-scope `@Dependent`, as stated in the [weld documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/scopescontexts.html#d0e1997):

> CDI features the so-called dependent pseudo-scope. This is the default
>   scope for a bean which does not explicitly declare a scope type. [...]
>   An instance of a dependent bean is never shared between different
>   clients or different injection points. It is strictly a dependent
>   object of some other object. It is instantiated when the object it
>   belongs to is created, and destroyed when the object it belongs to is
>   destroyed.

The [javadoc for this annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.0/) gives some more information about this scope:

> Beans declared with scope @Dependent behave differently to beans with
>   other built-in scope types. When a bean is declared to have scope
>   @Dependent:
>
> - No injected instance of the bean is ever shared between multiple    injection points.
> - Any instance of the bean injected into an object that is being    created by the container is bound to the lifecycle of the newly
>     created object.
> - When a Unified EL expression in a JSF or JSP page that refers to the    bean by its EL name is evaluated, at most one instance of the
>     bean is    instantiated. This instance exists to service just a single
>     evaluation of the EL expression. It is reused if the bean EL name
>     appears multiple times in the EL expression, but is never reused when 
>     the EL expression is evaluated again, or when another EL expression
>     is evaluated.
> - Any instance of the bean that receives a producer method, producer    field, disposer method or observer method invocation exists to
>     service that invocation only.
> - Any instance of the bean injected into method parameters of a    disposer method or observer method exists to service the method
>     invocation only.

Comment: Thank you, Matt. Have totally missed the part in the 1.0 docs. My bad.

Comment: No problem! Good to hear that it helped!