# @PostConstruct in invoked everytime an event come

Tags: java, cdi

I use CDI (Weld) in Java SE application. I made a Bean let's call it BeanA.

```
public class BeanA {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("INIT");
    }

    public void receive(@Observes String test) {
        System.out.println("received: " + test);
    }
}
```

In my test method I invoke:

```
Weld weld = new Weld();
WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();
Instance<BeanA> instance = container.instance().select(BeanA.class);
BeanA bean = instance.get();

container.event().fire("TEST");
container.event().fire("TEST");
container.event().fire("TEST");
container.event().fire("TEST");
```

Why output is like? Why @PostConstruct is called everytime event is received?:
INIT
INIT
recived: TEST
INIT
recived: TEST
INIT
recived: TEST
INIT
recived: TEST

Answer (score 6):

This is because the default scope of beans is [`@Dependent`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293510/what-is-the-default-scope-of-a-named-cdi-bean). This means that every time you fire an event, a new instance of your observer bean needs to be created so that the even gets sent to it. `@PostConstruct` gets invoked as part of that creation.

Annotate your `BeanA` type with `@Singleton` to set its scope to singleton. Only one will ever be created for your container.

Comment: You're better off using `@ApplicationScoped` over `@Singleton`, the behaviour is the same but the CDI provided scope is normal.

Comment: Ok but what if I want to have like 10 BeanA objects and send event to all of them?

Comment: @ryan I currently do not know how to do that.

Comment: @ryan please ask that as a separate question.